# MOSFET Current capability validation through SOA

Tags: mosfet, motor, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver

I want need more clarification on MOSFET SOA,
VDS and Id relation
Motor Driver Peak Current 45A Voltage 48Vdc

I'm considering one MOSFET whose Id mention 113A at 100°C

**1**. Vds=Rds_on*Id is that correct to check the relation according to this Vds=0.0071*50 i.e. 0.355V and if I check the 0.42V on x axis the respective current approx. 40A on y axis (which is limited by Rds_on of MOSFET).that is so I'm not operating safely

**2**. I'm using 48V battery to drive my BLDC motor, so shall I consider 48V as Vds X axis (blue mark in SOA image) to obtain respective current on Y axis of SOA (red mark in SOA image Fsw 10 kHz and pulse time 100 us). So the current is only 50A. almost at the margin what I required

I've checked with some other mosfet also which has 180A current at 100°C according 1 step the resp current is 130A
and by step to only 60A.

Above the rating the as per SOA,Mosfet  get Damaged
So please clarify which one of above step should be used to check mosfet safe operating Area.

also want to know when I will get to operate the mosfet at 113A,as mention in datasheet of MOSFET. or that is not practical

Waiting for a valuable reply
Thanks!

[image]
IPB039N10N3 G datasheet link: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPB039N10N3G-DS-v02_03-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ce5fb52011d1ed1fd3915e0

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your load?

Comment: Bldc motor which is driving the PUMP

Answer (score 0):

50A steady state would be P=50A^2*3.9mΩ or 9.75W (which is probably too much for the package to take) Check 9.75W with the junction to ambient thermal resistance and make sure the package temperature stays below what it's rated for (ie calculate the package temperature from the dissipated heat).

As far as SOA, I get 100uS so keep the pulses equal to or shorter than that. I would also put this into a spice sim to double check the heating with a load for sanities sake.

Comment: actually I'm using 2 MOSFET in parallel

Comment: Could you please help me to understand which method should be use to check the MOSFET SOA step 1 or step 2 it's just for my reference only

Comment: I'm still confuse in SOA, You've mention " I get 100uS so keep the pulses equal to or shorter than that"

Answer (score 0):

On a log-log scale the SOA sloped limits represent constant max energy with equal space between the lines for log time scales.  This is for peak energy flux in the chip.

The spec for 113A is for DC only with the caveats for margin and heatinsk.

The DC curve is for max power dissipation.

Adequate heat sinks are critical to maintain case temp limits well below limits as they have an Ron with a PTC pos.,tempco.  This allows parallel use, but with very fast rise-times, not always so.  This is only for pulse width with reasonable rise-times. Further reading is suggested  on this subject.